# not able to get desired data in mongoose query with mongoose query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

This is my code below

```
 let startDateTimeStr = start_date + "T00:00:00.0000000"; // Making sure to match the number of zeros in the format
      let endDateTimeStr = end_date + "T00:00:00.0000000";
      matchCase.push({
        "start.dateTime": {
          $gte: startDateTimeStr,
        },
        "end.dateTime": {
          $lte: endDateTimeStr,
        },
      });
```

I need to get data from data from other collection here . What i want is that from my field I want  to select email ids whose status is declined. The schema looks like this in appointments collection

attendees which has array of documents which has status which has response field ,emailAddress field which has address in it.

The address contains email address. Select on the basis of response if it is declined .

then look up for matching email address in user collection and return me there the user_serial_id but it returns me nothing. Here is what my full code looks like

```
matchCase.push({
  "start.dateTime": {
    $gte: startDateTimeStr,
  },
  "end.dateTime": {
    $lte: endDateTimeStr,
  },
});

matchCase.push({
  "attendees.status.response": { $ne: "declined" },
});

let addFieldsQuery = {
  $addFields: {
    nonDeclinedEmails: {
      $map: {
        input: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$attendees",
            as: "attendee",
            cond: { $ne: ["$$attendee.status.response", "declined"] }
          }
        },
        as: "nonDeclined",
        in: "$$nonDeclined.email"
      }
    }
  }
};

let lookupQuery = {
  $lookup: {
    from: "users",
    localField: "nonDeclinedEmails",
    foreignField: "email",
    as: "nonDeclinedUsers"
  }
};
let projectQuery = {
  $project: {
    user_id: 1,
    description: 1,
    title: "$subject",
    start: "$start.dateTime",
    end: "$end.dateTime",
    type: "appointment",
    resource: "$nonDeclinedUsers.user_serial_id", // populated from lookup
    recurrence: "$recurrence",
    editable: { $toBool: 0 }
  }
};


let aggregatQuery = [];

if (matchCase.length > 0) {
  aggregatQuery.push({
    $match: {
      $and: matchCase
    }
  });
}

aggregatQuery.push(addFieldsQuery);  // add fields for non-declined emails
aggregatQuery.push(lookupQuery);  // perform lookup to get autotask_id

if (Object.keys(projectQuery).length > 0) {
  aggregatQuery.push(projectQuery);
}

console.log(`User id is ${userId}`);

return aggregatQuery;
```

and then
i execute this code

```
let appointmentsQry = await AppointmentsQuery(req, res);
    
    appointments = await appointmentsModel.aggregate(appointmentsQry).exec();
```

Comment: Would be great to provide sample data to reproduce the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the $lookup stage the local field is `nonDeclinedEmails` which is an array and the foreign field is `email`.

That will only match documents in the users collection whose email field contains exactly (including same order) the nonDeclinedEmails list.

You probably need to $unwind the nonDeclinedEmails list first.

Comment: I will try it and keep you updated about it. Thanks for your effort.